# Python - create many lists with random values

Tags: python, list

I want many (hundreds) of lists in python that follow this form:

```
[random.randint(1,100), random.randint(50, 100), random.randint(10,20), random.randint(1,100)]
```

And I want to name them list1, list2, list3, etc. all the way up to list500, list501, etc.

Is there a way to automate that all? Or should I not be using lists?

Comment: not clear what you asking

Comment: What do you mean 'want to call them'?

Comment: whats the logic behind the scope of random function ?

Comment: @aruisdante Sorry, I meant I want to name them those. Essentially concatenate the word "list" with the numbers hundreds of times.

Comment: Why would you want to have 500 separate variables? Just put them all in a list.

Comment: @japem Right, but name them *where*?

Comment: @poke it is much more organized the way I want to do it. I could, but it would be a real pain.

Comment: No, creating ~500 variables is a real pain.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 my_lists = [[random.randint(1,100), random.randint(50, 100), random.randint(10,20), random.randint(1,100)] for x in range(500)]
```

demo for 5:

```
>>> my_lists [[random.randint(1,100), random.randint(50, 100), random.randint(10,20), random.randint(1,100)] for x in range(5)]
>>> my_lists
[[98, 58, 15, 63], [69, 59, 12, 37], [62, 58, 16, 7], [55, 97, 17, 55], [98, 53, 14, 90]]
```

Comment: what about the name of the list ? the OP what to assign the list to a name !

Comment: That works. It doesn't exactly create separate lists, which is what I ideally wanted, but it's good enough. Thanks.

Comment: no need to create saperate list you can access the nested list by index, creating another variable is not good idea

Comment: @japem you need to use a dictionary

Comment: its like index 0 is list1, index 1 is list2 and so one

Comment: @Kasra it's ok to have them be list[0], list[1] and so on instead of list1, list2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple snippet that will created 'named' lists inside a `dict`:

```
rand_lists = dict(('list{}'.format(i), [random.randint(1,100), random.randint(50, 100), random.randint(10,20), random.randint(1,100)]) for i in xrange(1,501))
rand_lists['list437']
>>> [3,52,12,90]
```